# Generate match lists from two dimensional map

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a two-dimensional map that describes the links between two types of variables, which looks something like this:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(vector(), 4, 4))
rownames(df) <- c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4")
colnames(df) <- c("y1", "y2", "y3", "y4")
df["x1","y3"] <- 1
df["x2","y2"] <- 1
df["x4","y4"] <- 1
df["x2","y3"] <- 1
```

The actual dataframe is roughly 1000x100 in size. For each row, I need to generate a list of all the columns with a 1 in that row. The actual dataframe has 1000 rows and 100 columns, so I'm looking for the most efficient process possible.

I tried using nested for loops, but this process is quite inefficient. Is there a faster way?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and iterate over the rows, using `which` to identify which columns have a 1. The `names` function just gives the column name rather than the index.

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) names(which(x == 1)))
# $x1
# [1] "y3"
# 
# $x2
# [1] "y2" "y3"
# 
# $x3
# character(0)
# 
# $x4
# [1] "y4"
```